# AudioStreamer appDelegate

Tags: iphone, ios4, audiostreamer

I have two things concerning `AudioStreamer` and i hope I'm getting some clues here:

**1.** I have set up a `UITabBarController` and in my `Appdelegate` is a `AudioStreamer`-Object. Two views refer to the `appDelegate.streamer`. It it looks like that im getting two sessions when i release and alloc it new. I get two running audiosession.

**2.** I use a `UITableView` to play out of this list. in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`-method I initialize with a URL. when the user taps with a fast double, or tripple-click. the audiosession will get startet three times. although i'm using a `bool` to prevent that. so my dirty solution is to set the system sleeping for a second. it is ugly because the screen freezes for a sec.

Thankfull for some hints

Simon

Answer (score 0):

In terms of your problems, it sounds like you should implement your AudioSteamer as a singleton, as this will prevent multiple instances from being created and provide a single point to control playback (i.e.: prevent multiple taps from triggering multiple playbacks).

For more information on how to create a singleton class, see the "Creating a Singleton Instance" section within Apple's [Cocoa Fundamentals Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW31).

Comment: All my subviews dont have the streamer as object. only in appDelegate is a streamer-object. So I think im using singelton.

Comment: @Simon - If you were using a singleton it would be impossible to have two instances and hence "two running audiosession".

Answer (score 0):

for 2nd point. It is a bug of AudioStreamer class. Also this has been solved and code is put up on [gitHub see link](https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer/issues/26). also if this does not seems working then you can go to the pause method and add more states as below

```
-(void)pause
{
    if (state==AS_PLAYING || state==AS_BUFFERING || state==AS_WAITING_FOR_DATA)
    {
       //rest code goes same....
    }
    // rest code goes same....
}
```

this solved my same problem. Hope this will help you also...